# Is the Set of Intervals A = {[a, b) : 0 ≤ a ≤ b < ∞} ∪ {[ a, ∞) : 0 ≤ a < ∞} a σ-Algebra on Ω = [0, ∞)?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

I am refreshing my statistics knowledge and found the exercise below. I would appreciate any feedback on whether my solution is remotely correct or how to solve this exercise properly. Also, I don't know how to express my solution properly in mathematical terms.

**Question**

Given $\Omega = [0, \infty)$.
Is $\mathcal{A} = \{[a, b) : 0 \leq a \leq b \lt \infty \} \cup \{[a, ∞) : 0 ≤ a < ∞\}$ a $\sigma$-algebra?

**Answer**

The $\sigma$-algebra has to satisfy these properties:

1. $\Omega \in \mathcal{A}$.

   True, because $0 \leq a$, so $[0, \infty) \in \mathcal{A}$.
2. $A \in \mathcal{A} \Rightarrow \overline{A} \in \mathcal{A}$

   <strike>True, because if $[3,6) \in \mathcal{A}$, then the complement $[0, 3) \cup [6, \infty)$ can be built with the definition of $\mathcal{A}$, so the complement is also in $\mathcal{A}$.</strike>

   **Edit (thanks @Tzimmo):** False, because if $[3,6) \in \mathcal{A}$, then the complement is $[0, 3) \cup [6, \infty)$. But the definition of $\mathcal{A}$ only allows for connected intervals.
3. $A_i \in \mathcal{A} \forall_i \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \in \mathcal{A}$

   False, because if $A = [1,3) \in \mathcal{A}$ and $[5,7) \in \mathcal{A}$, then the union has the be in $\mathcal{A}$. But the definition of $\mathcal{A}$ only allows a union of two intervals, where the second interval always goes to $\infty$.

I think that the third property is not satisfied. So my solution would be that $\mathcal{A}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega = [0, \infty)$

Is that correct? How would I properly prove this?

Comment: Your thinking is quite right. $\cal A$ only contains connected intervals, but a union of two elements of $\cal A$ is not guaranteed to be connected. The proof is just to give the counter-example you have found :$[1, 3)$ and $[5, 7)$ are members of $\cal A$ whose union is not a member of $\cal A$ (and maybe to spell out the details of why this is so, if you feel you are expected to).

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by $\mathcal{A}$ contains only connected intervals? Do you mean it should only contain connected intervals because of the definition of $\Omega$? Appreciate your help!

Comment: Actually, point 2 should fail already. $\mathcal{A}$ does not contain unions of two intervals. Elements are either of the form $[a,b)$ or $[a,\infty)$. The complement of $[3,6)$ is not of that shape.

Comment: The intervals that make up $\cal A$ are all connected. @Tzimmo is also right that point 2 fails for the same reason.

Comment: I think I have a mistake in my thinking. If I choose $a = 0$ and $b = 2$ for the first interval, then I have $[0, 2)$. And if I choose $a = 6$ for the second interval, I have $[6, \infty)$. The union of both would then be $\{[0, 2), [6, \infty)\}$. Isn't that the complement of $[3, 6)$?

Comment: You are confusing $\mathcal{A}$ with the set $\{[a,b) \cup [c,\infty) : 0 \leq a < b < c \leq \infty\}$. The elements of $\mathcal{A}$ are not unions of two intervals, but $\mathcal{A}$ itself is the union. Elements of $\mathcal{A}$ are *either* of the form $[a,b)$ *or* of the form $[a,\infty)$. The union captures the "either … or" part.

Comment: I see, now I understand my mistake. Thanks for making that clear to me @Tzimmo!